# Wildcard Prefix Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

is there a way in Laravel 5 to have a recognized list of prefixes, such as ['gbr','en','eu'], so that

```
/gbr/bar/baz/shoelace  // or
/eu/bar/baz/shoelace
```

is handled by the same controller@method as

```
/bar/baz/shoelace
```

Except that the additional parameter `foo=gbr` is passed in the first condition?

Note the `Route::group` prefix won't work because there may or may not be a prefix in this case.  Also, this strategy should take precedence over all else, i.e. the Route would check for the (optional) prefix first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

When declaring your routes, you can declare them as

```
Route::get('{prefix}/bar/baz/shoelace', 'controller@method')->where('prefix', 'gbr|en|eu');
```

`gbr|en|eu` is a simple regular expression that will match either the string `gbr, en or eu`. Check out [Regular expression constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) for more details

And in your controller you can have

```
public function method($prefix) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: OK, that's the right Idea and I think I've seen that before, but is there any way to throttle it so that `{prefix}` is only a specific known list of values?

Comment: Yes there is a way to throttle. Check the updated answer. It can be done with Regular expression constraints. Hope this helps.